I found a error "Exception has occurred. Unknown signal" when debug my Quicksort code made by myself. What is this error?
`#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

void quicksort(int *n, int length){
if(length > 1){
    int *left, *right;
    int leftLength = 0, rightLength = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
    if(n[i] <= n[length - 1]){
        int *tmp = left;
        leftLength++;
        left = new int[leftLength];
        for(int j = 0; j < leftLength - 1; j++){
            left[j] = tmp[j];
        }
        left[leftLength - 1] = n[i];
        delete[] tmp;
    }else{
        int *tmp = right;
        rightLength++;
        right = new int[rightLength];
        for(int j = 0; j < rightLength - 1; j++){
            right[j] = tmp[j];
        }
        right[rightLength - 1] = n[i];
        delete[] tmp;
    }
    }
    if(leftLength > 1)quicksort(left,leftLength);
    if(rightLength > 1)quicksort(right,rightLength);

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        if(i < leftLength)n[i] = left[i]; else n[i] = right[i - leftLength];
    }
    delete[] left;
    delete[] right;
}
}
int main(){
//MY_CODE
}`

I thought it is because of memory and i have tried to delete all temp memory after use. But it still error. If i don't delete tmp it will alert "Exception has occurred. Segmentation fault" but when i add delete tmp it alerts "Exception has occurred. Unknown signal"
If you find any problem in my code please let me known.

Your code is  more like "C" then it is "C++", quicksort can run fully in-place so no new memory allocations should not be needed. Passing arrays like this int *n, int length in C++ is not recommended any more use std::span<int>. For your current code replace new int[..] withstd::vector<int> and instead of [i] then use at(i) and start debugging because you are bound to access some memory out of bound.

On a cursory glance, you have uninitialized pointer variables left and right, and before you reassign these, you are storing the old indeterminate value in tmp and later calling array-delete on that. This will result in undefined behavior, and likely cause exceptions similar to what you're seeing. Note that in C++ you should not be using manual memory management like this. Use std::vector. As a side-note, quicksort does not require temporary arrays.

Read this, it explains more about in-place quicksort
https://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs2321/www/newLectures/11_Quick_Sort.html

There are multiple issues with this code. Turn up the compiler warnings and pay attention to them. https://godbolt.org/z/fxTPbqe7E Learn to use a debugger and step through the code line by line so you can see what is happening and if it is working the way you expect.

Fixing the initialization problem with left and right turns into a stack overflow.

That isn't similar to quicksort in any way.
